# Union of intersection of a family of sets (and viceversa)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For $n,k$ define 
$A_n^k = [ -a, a ]$ where $$ a = ~1 - \left(\frac1 2\right)^k + (n-k)(n-k-1) $$
Then
$$B_1 = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n^k$$
 $$B_2 = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n^k$$

How should I understand this intersection of an union and vice versa? How can we consider the intersection with respect to to $k$, when will the union  be $\mathbb{R}$?

What should be the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we see that $a\to\infty$ for $n\to\infty$. This means $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^k = \mathbb R$, which implies $B_1 = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb R = \mathbb R$.

Second, we see that $\min_{n>1} a = 1 - 0.5^k$, which occures for $n=k$.
Thus, we have
$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n^k = [-b_k,b_k]$, where 
$$b_k = 1 - 0.5^k.$$

We see that $b_k\to 1$ for $k\to\infty$. Thus, we have $B_2 = [-1,1]$.

Comment: I think it is implicit that $n$ and $k$ are integers, so for any fixed $k$ the minimum of $(n-k)(n-k-1)$ is $0$ rather than $-\frac14$. Therefore $B_2=(-1,1)$.